# How to detect leading double-quote in a string in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a tokenizer that reads code from a file and am having difficulty with the - seemingly - trivial task of getting it to branch into the case that handles string constants (any token that starts and ends with a double quote).

The conditional I wrote for the branch is

`if (token.charAt(0) == '"') { // Do some stuff }`

where `token` is the string that was read in.

Alternatively, I've also tried

`if (token.startsWith("\"")) { // Do some stuff }`

I've checked the debugger and it still refuses to enter the branch even for valid cases such as the string `"Paris"` with value field `[”, P, a, r, i, s, ”]`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The tilted double quote `”` is different from the double quote `"` that you're specifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left `”` and right `“` double quotes are different from the standard double quote character `"`. Try doing a `replace()` on the string to replace all left and right double quotes with the standard double quote before tokenizing.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. It never occurred to me that anything other than the standard double quote would be used, thanks.